# Simulate modal call when i press button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

Im using Codeigniter and Bootstrap in my project, I have a button that call a Modal, before calling Modal i do some test with ajax, so I have removed data-target from button and i added in test after ajax success, my problem is i should hit button tow times to call Modal the first time add attr and the second called Modal, I need to use jquery to simulate the action of clicking buttons and adding attribute data-target in the sometime without double-click . How do I achieve it? Can I achieve it with jQuery?

this is my code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="ppp" data-toggle="modal"  data-ms="1"  data-idpt="<?php echo $idPatient ?>" data-nbrsc="<?php echo $nbrSc; ?>" data-tarifsc="<?php echo $tarifSc; ?>" >
                   + Réglememt</button>
                   <script type="text/javascript">

                          $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#ppp").click(function(event){
                              event.preventDefault();
                              var dtab = $("tr.active td:first").html();
                                jQuery.ajax({
                                  type: "POST",
                                  url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>esthetique/ajax_pm",
                                  dataType:'json',
                                  data:{dtab: dtab},

                                  success:function(res){
                                     document.getElementById('dangerlist').innerHTML ='';
                                    if(res.dtab==null){
                                        document.getElementById('dangerlist').innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='error' role='alert'></div>";
                                        $('#error').text('Veuillez selectionner un traitement');
                                    }else{
                                          if(res.paiemsg==1){

                                            document.getElementById('dangerlist').innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-info' id='error' role='alert'></div>";
                                            $('#error').text('Impossible d\'ajouter paiement : Traitement déja réglée');
                                          }else{
                                              $("#ppp").attr("data-target","#addpm");
                                              $('#ppp').click();
                                          }

                                    }

                                  }  
                                });
                            });
                        });
               </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding attribute and triggering second click just use the Bootstrap method `modal()`

```
  $("#ppp").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>esthetique/ajax_pm",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {dtab: $("tr.active td:first").html()},
    success: function (res) {
      document.getElementById('dangerlist').innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='error' role='alert'></div>";

      if (res.dtab == null) {
        $('#error').text('Veuillez selectionner un traitement');
        return;
      }

      if (res.paiemsg == 1) {
        $('#error').text('Impossible d\'ajouter paiement : Traitement déja réglée');
        return;
      }

      document.getElementById('dangerlist').innerHTML = '';
      // $("#ppp").attr("data-target", "#addpm");
      $("#myModal").modal()
    }

  });
});
```

Moins de lignes de code est mieux, non?

Comment: thanks @Dfriend for your effort, i want to add att and activate action of the button because when  i click button i add attribute but i can't call Modal so i should click an othertime to have call modal

Comment: See my revised answer. Note: I have assumed the id for the model is "myModal"